# Can Linux reliably run from an SD card?

Tags: sd-card

If I were to install and run Debian Linux from an SD card or microSD card, would this be less reliable than running from a regular HDD (e.g. a 2.5" Western Digital Blue)? The system and home folders would all be placed on the SD card.

Comment: Raspberry Pis run off SD cards and they're fine

Answer (score 1):

It will only be limited by the quality of the SD card and slot.  The SD card should at least have a much lower latency than your rotating hard drive.

This is an approved Debian installation method, as shown here:
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/HowTo/InstallOnSDcardOrUsbStick